# User command shortcut for limits

Tags: math-mode

I'm a grey headed guy taking a calculus class. I'm trying to figure out how to make a user command with two arguments to generate limit statement with right arrow. I keep having to type `\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}` blah blah.

So, I would like shortcut with first param as in `x` above and second param where the limit is going to.

Comment: `\newcommand\mylim[2]{\lim_{#1\rightarrow#2}}` and `\mylim{x}{\infty}` (in math mode), or with an optional argument defaulting to "x":
`\newcommand\mylim[2][x]{\lim_{#1\rightarrow#2}}` and `\mylim{\infty}` and `\mylim[y]{\infty}`

Comment: Instead of a command, you could use an editor (or a third party program) which lets you insert snippets.

Answer (score 9):

To define new macros (you might call them commands, shortcuts, etc.) in LaTeX, we use `\newcommand` (or `\renewcommand` if we want to use the name of an existing macro). So we start with

```
\newcommand{\mylim}{code goes here}
```

where `\mylim` is the name of the macro we want to define.
In the second set of curly parentheses, we add the code we want to use as a shortcut.
We use a hash `#` and a number to denote the first input, second input, and so on.
So we'd write:

```
\newcommand{\mylim}{\lim_{#1 \to #2}}
```

Then we need to tell LaTeX that this command takes two mandatory arguments, so we add `[2]` between the name of the macro, and the definition:

```
\newcommand{\mylim}[2]{\lim_{#1 \to #2}}
```

More information about defining new macros can be found on [this Wikibooks page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros).

And here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mylim}[2]{\lim_{#1 \to #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \mylim{x}{\infty} blah\;blah
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]